# TypeError: Object of type Reporter is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to add the reporter with ajax but it is not working properly. When I send json data with `{'reporter':reporter.name}` then it creates the obj in the database successfully but I am not being able to display this newly created obj in the select option. I have to refresh to see this object in the select option. Then I tried sending the object instance as a JsonResponse by dumping with `json.dumps(obj)` but I am getting this error serializable error.

I have to create the reporter object and display in the select option without page refresh. How can I do it ? What's wrong here in my approach ?

view

```
class AddReporterView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        reporter = Reporter.objects.create(name=name)
        data = {
            'reporter': json.dumps(reporter)
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Scripts

```
$(document).on('submit','#target-category-form',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: {
                name:$('#name').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success: handleFormSuccess,

        });
    });
    function handleFormSuccess(data){
              $("#id-categories").html(data);
              $('#modalOpen').modal('toggle');
               console.log(data);
                }
```

I want to display the created data here in this html select element

```
<select class="form-control" name="reporter" multiple="multiple" id="id-categories">

                        {% for reporter in reporters %}
                        <option value="{{reporter.pk}}">{{reporter.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}

                    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an instance to a dictionary, you can use `model_to_dict`.

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

reporter = Reporter.objects.first()
data = {'reporter': model_to_dict(reporter)}
```

By default, the serialization is done implicitly in the `JsonResponse` using `json.dumps` so you don't need to bother with it

```
# glimpse of source code.
class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, **kwargs):
        ...
        data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder, **json_dumps_params)
        super().__init__(content=data, **kwargs)
```

### EDIT

```
// add this to your success callback
// you can create option either in python or javascript.
success: function(data){ 
      // on success, dynamically append the select drop down list 
      $('#id-categories').append(`<option value =${data.reporter.id}> ${data.reporter.name}</option>`)  
}
```

Comment: +1 it remove this  error but I am not being able to display this created object on the select option. I need to refresh to view it. How can i do it ?

Comment: still have to refresh